# C++ template function aliases as variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

I'm trying to create a template that allows a caller to specify their own well-formed allocation method, but I'm having issues with passing the variadic template arguments.

If I don't pass any arguments, everything works as expected; however, if I pass one or more arguments, I get a compile error "too many arguments to function call".

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
using allocator = std::unique_ptr<T>(Args...);

template <typename T, allocator<T> A, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> get(Args... args) {
  return A(args...);
}

int main() {
  auto up1 = get<int, std::make_unique<int>>();  // Works

  auto up2 = get<int, std::make_unique<int>>(1);  // Too many arguments
                                                  // expected 0, have 1

  printf("%d\n", *up1);
  printf("%d\n", *up2);
}
```

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd68dec6691d5323) _works_, but is this really the interface you want..? This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166663) to me.

Comment: I may refactor to change the interface, but I'm still interested in understanding the underlying problem.  Why does the variadic argument not work with the template alias in this case?

Comment: `allocator<T> ` is `allocator<T, empty-pack>` which is `std::unique_ptr<T>()` which is then adjusted to `std::unique_ptr<T> (*)()`.

Comment: That makes sense, T.C.  Is is possible to define the template in such a way so that allocator can use the variadic?  I can't do allocator<T, Args...> because the template parameter is defined before the variadic Args parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead allow and deduce the type of a possibly stateful *functor* A. A few more braces but it's harder to get this wrong:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
struct allocator{
    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const { 
        return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename A = allocator<T>>
auto get(A a=A{}) {
    return [a](auto... args){ 
        return a(args...); 
    };
};


int main() {
  auto up0 = get<int>()(); 
  auto up1 = get<int>()(1); 
  auto up0b = get<int>(allocator<int>())();
  auto up1b = get<int>(allocator<int>())(1);
  auto up0c = get<int>([](auto ... args){ return std::make_unique<int>(args...); })();
  auto up1c = get<int>([](auto ... args){ return std::make_unique<int>(args...); })(1);

  printf("%d\n", *up0);
  printf("%d\n", *up0b);
  printf("%d\n", *up0c);
  printf("%d\n", *up1);
  printf("%d\n", *up1b);
  printf("%d\n", *up1c);
}
```

Note also that I use `make_unique` also in `allocator` but you *could* make a version that accept a pointer to construct the `unique_ptr` with.

[Live DEMO here](https://ideone.com/L0NNuk)

Comment: I did, but I have less than 15 rep (new account) so it isn't displayed.